# Killing tasks in Python

Tags: python

This is my program to compile python code with PyInstaller without doing it by hand:

```
prog = raw_input('File to compile: ')
shutil.copy(prog,'C:\Users\Hydro\Desktop\Projects\Python\PyInstaller\\'+prog)
os.chdir('PyInstaller\\')
subprocess.call(['python', 'PyInstaller.py', prog, '--onefile'])
x = os.getpid()
print x
os.kill(x,9)
var = prog.split('.')
new_var = var[0]
os.chdir(new_var+'\\'+'dist')
shutil.copy(new_var+'.'+'exe','C:\Users\Hydro\Desktop\Projects\Python')
shutil.rmtree('C:\Users\Hydro\Desktop\Projects\Python\PyInstaller\\'+new_var)
os.remove('C:\Users\Hydro\Desktop\Projects\Python\PyInstaller\\'+prog)
raw_input('File Compiled. Press Enter to Exit')
```

This doesn't work due to the fact that a process is using the dir that i am trying to delete.

I have asked why on the PyIRC but to no avail.. I have also tried killing the PID but i'm killing the wrong ones.

Would anyone be able to help me or tell me as to why this is disallowing me to delete the dir after compilation? So i can come up with a solution?

Comment: are you sure the issue is not related to the single '\' in your strings?

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening in your code: `x = os.getpid(); os.kill(x,9)` Are you trying to kill yourself? What am I missing here?

Comment: @zenpoy, i very much doubt it.

Comment: @freakish, yeah its stupid i know. I am trying to kill the PID that is using the dir that i am trying to delete lol.

Comment: It would still be safer to use `\\ ` instead of `\ `, or a raw string like `r"C:\Users\me\Desktop\\"`. Or just use forward slashes since Windows can interpret them, too.

Comment: @NiklasR Can you explain why?

Comment: Imagine a path like `"C:\Users\niklas\Desktop"`. There you go: a new-line in the string.

Comment: @NiklasR To be safe OP should use `os.path.join()`.

Comment: Are you both implying that this method can be exploited?

Comment: @vjgaero No. It's just it might not work under other systems. Using `os.path` fixes that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your application is the one to use the directory you are trying to remove. by invoking `os.chdir()` you will change the current working dir to a different one before deleting the dir:

```
org_dir = os.getcwd()

... # your stuff

os.chdir(org_dir)
# delete the dir
```

Comment: Instead of changing the work directory, is it possible to just get rid of it?

Comment: @vjgaero: I doubt it. the current working directory is the current path your application is working from: http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/3.1/diveintopython3/html/comprehensions.html#getcwd